# How to have two types in an html input

Tags: html

So I would like to know how can I have type hidden and type submit in an input?

```
<input type="submit" id = "submitid" type = "hidden">
```

Comment: Why? You can't do it, let make 2 input tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that:

1) Take the id of input and add a *style* for it with **display: none** attribute.

OR

2) Set the type hidden to the input, put it in a form, and submit it through pure Javascript.